# How to find microarchitecture given the CPU name?

Tags: cpu, microarchitecture

How do I find out the microarchitecture of a processor if I know its name?

For example, if I find that someone I'm trying to help says he has a `Intel i7 960 3.2GHz` CPU, I want to find out what is the microarchitecture (like Sandy Bridge, Haswell etc.) of that processor. It can be found by a bit of Googling, but I'm looking for a comprehensive list or a tool that gives me this information for any CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Use [CPU-z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) or [HWInfo](http://www.hwinfo.com/) to find out those details.

CPU-z:

[image]

HWInfo:

[image]

Comment: This answer needs a SE approved Freehand Red Circle to be complete ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek done ;p

Comment: what if I need to find the info from commandline/linux shell?